# The best way to do a 301 redirect with a delay of several seconds?

Tags: php, redirect, delay

What is the best way to do a 301 redirect with a delay of several seconds? I want the original page to be displayed for 5-10 seconds and then do a 301 redirect to another site. I've found a lot of solutions in PHP on google but the only one I found with a delay didn't display the original page before redirecting—only an empty screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really do a true 301 redirect with a delay. HTTP is stateless.  For a "301 redirect", which is what you want if you're trying to make google happy; the client sends a request, and the status code on the reply from the server will be 301, also as part of the reply you'll use a location header and tell where the new content is.  If you don't have all that, you're not doing a 301 redirect.

With the other answer, you're doing a meta refresh on the client side, which google does not like.

This is how you do a 301, and the user doesn't even see the old page at all, and probably will have no idea they've even been redirected.

```
$location="http://www.yoursite.com/newpage";
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: '.$location);
```

Comment: Thanks. After searching google for a solution that's what I was already kinda thinking. I guess I'll have to do a delayed 302 for now and then switch to a 301 in a few weeks when most everyone has seen the delay screen.

Answer (score 7):

```
You're being redirected
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5;URL=the-other-page.html">
```

or in PHP

```
header( 'refresh: 5; url=/the-other-page.html' );
echo 'You\'re being redirected';
```

It is better to choose second solution, though

Comment: Don't forget to add the `click here if your page doesn't refresh`, some panicky people disable refreshes, and have then no easy way of knowing where they should go.

Comment: @oliverwhite you should favor server-side redirects (example #2) over client-side redirects. And you should add an HTTP-status-code (301 or 302) to determine, whether this is a permanent redirect or just a temporary one.

Comment: Neither of those are 301 redirects.

Comment: @feeala: Edited ("It is better to choose second solution, though")

Comment: @profitphp: does it matter? It does the same except for hidden code (hidedn for normal members)

Comment: @genesis: people having disabled refreshes usually have both meta & header refreshes disabled. So always provide a fallback.

Comment: Thanks. Even though those aren't 301's, I need the delay for now so I'll have to use the PHP method you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not the coding type, but you want an amazingly versatile free tool, I endorse Quick Pagepost Redirect Plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

`In this case you want to use a meta redirect.`

This plugin can handle Wordpress redirects and meta redirects (in case you need a delay)

It supports 301, 302, 307, and meta redirects.
You can add URL's to avoid 404's also.

If you are upgrading a site and changing page urls and wish to preserve seo ranking, this is the tool my friend uses (he's a pro)

This will do it all - no coding.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with these guys in any way.